# AccessibilityService is not responding on OnKeyEvent()

Tags: java, android, service, automation, accessibility

Hi I am building an accessibility service. I wanted to deal with the keyboard inputs, and also determine `BACK` key events. I guess my best shot is overriding the `onKeyEvent()` callback. But What I found out is that it is even never being called. I tried to add `android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true`" in configuration XML and also in the `onServiceConnected` module I added

```
info.flags=AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_FILTER_KEY_EVENTS;
        info.flags=AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS;
        setServiceInfo(info);
```

But still no luck. Looks like the even `onKeyEvent` is never raised.

Comment: You are using the `=` operator to set flags to only contain `FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS`. Remove the `setServiceInfo` and `flags=` calls entirely and just rely on the configuration XML. Post your configuration XML.

Comment: `onKeyEvent()` receives events only if your service is the first one to register for key events. So, it's unreliable. Which is why there's no way to intercept button click events through accessibility.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle the events of the homebutton and back button, you have to add this:

In your xml service declareted:

```
1-android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
2-Add flagRequestFilterKeyEvents to your android:accessibilityFlags
```

In your accessibility service class add onKeyEvent:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Back");

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Home");
                    return false;
            }
            return super.onKeyEvent(event);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure, you can try it

Comment: this is not working on soft keys e.g. back,home,recent button